# How do I define a global onCompletion camel route in xml?

Tags: xml, apache-camel

According to Camel documentation a global onCompletion can be defined in xml, however when trying that I get: `org.apache.camel.xml.io.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected element '{}onCompletion'`

My route definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes>

    <onCompletion parallelProcessing="true">
        <to uri="myproc:camel/onCompletionProcessor" />
    </onCompletion>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start-success-route" />
        <to uri="mock:result" />
    </route>
</routes>
```

Comment: Curly brackets are usually when json is used (not xml).  Do you need to add Content-Type to you request?

Comment: Thanks. It was a schema problem, as onCompletion is not a routes child, unless you use java DSL, where it can be configured in a RouteBuilder.configure() block.